# REST Application - I don't receive the error from server in case of insucess - the output displays only if the request is successfull

Tags: rest

I have the next problem: I've made a simple application which retrieves information from a server (GET Method). The application works fine as long as the information is retrieved successfully.

In case of insuccess, I don't receive the error from the server (ex: 401 - Unauthorized, 
**403 - Forbidden** - when the authentication token is incorrect for example).

1. How can I fix this so that my application will return the error from server ? I've done also a POST method and there it's working, I received all erorrs froem server in case of insuccess.
2. What i'm doing wrong with this code ? Why i don't receive an error in case of insuccess?

   - The only error I receive in **output is 400** in all scenarios and this isn't enough.
   - For example, if the authorization token is incorrect, I should receive from server 401 - Unauthorized. I know this because i'm doing test with other REST application (like POSTMAN). Can it be fixed to show the errors related to that scenarios ?

```html
 void example2() {
       
// GET METHOD !
        
       try {
   String webPage = "https://www.clients.ro";
   String name = "user";
   String password = "pass";

   String authString = name + ":" + password;
   System.out.println("Decoded authorization token" + authString);
   //byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
   //String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
                        
                        byte[] authEncBytes = authString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                                 String authStringEnc = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(authEncBytes);
                        
   System.out.println("Token encoded in Base64 " + authStringEnc);

   URL url = new URL(webPage);
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
   urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
   InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

   int numCharsRead;
   char[] charArray = new char[1024];
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
    sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
   }
   String result = sb.toString();

   
   System.out.println(result);
   System.out.println();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is the error i'm receiveing when i put for example a wrong authentication token (i should receive from server - 401 Unauthorized) java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://www.clients.ro (it's an example, i use correct URL)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1838)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURL

Comment: Nevermind, i figure it out by myself ! :D